Spring cloud API Gateway fails when route to downstream services for those API endpoints which need authentication and gives 401
Hi I'm having a problem with my API gateway which is built on Spring cloud. I have implemented JWT authentication mechanism in API gateway and also on one of the microservice(user service). The problem is when a url is hit that needs to be authenticated it shows 401 from the API gateway itself , From the logs its clear that JWT validation is successful. When those url is added to the excluded routes(those which need not to be authenticated) it works perfectly. I will share the code snippets. Any suggestions on what could be causing the 401 error or advice on troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.
GatewaySecurityConfig :
package com.OrderIt.api_gateway.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class GatewaySecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)  // Updated syntax for disabling CSRF
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
                                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").permitAll()  // Allow POST requests to /api/user
//                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/api/item/**").authenticated()// Allow unauthenticated access to /authenticate
//                        .anyExchange().authenticated()  // Require authentication for all other endpoints
                ).addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)  // Disable HTTP Basic authentication
                .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable);
        return http.build();
    }
}

JwtAuthFilter :

package com.OrderIt.api_gateway.auth;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    private final AntPathMatcher pathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

    // Define the list of excluded routes with HTTP methods
    private final List<RouteConfig> excludedRoutes = List.of(
            new RouteConfig("/api/user", HttpMethod.POST), // Exclude POST requests to /api/user
            new RouteConfig("/api/auth/**", null)      // Exclude all requests to /api/auth/**
//            new RouteConfig("/api/item/**", null)
    );

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        log.debug("JwtAuthFilter is processing the request");
        String path = exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath();
        HttpMethod method = exchange.getRequest().getMethod();

        log.debug("Incoming request path: {}, method: {}", path, method);

        // Skip JWT validation for excluded routes
        if (shouldExclude(path, method)) {
            log.debug("Skipping JWT validation for excluded route: {}, method: {}", path, method);
            return chain.filter(exchange); // Continue without validating JWT
        }

        // JWT validation starts here
        String authHeader = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            log.warn("Missing or invalid Authorization header");
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }

        String token = authHeader.substring(7); // Extract the token after "Bearer "
        if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            log.warn("Invalid JWT token");
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }

        log.debug("JWT token validated successfully");

        // Forward the token to downstream services
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest()
                .mutate()
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader) // Forward the auth header
                .build();

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build())
                .doOnSuccess(aVoid -> {
                    log.debug("Successfully completed processing for path: {}", path);
                })
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    log.error("Error occurred while processing for path: {}, error: {}", path, throwable.getMessage());
                })
                .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    log.debug("Response status code: {}", exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode());
                }));
    }

    private boolean shouldExclude(String path, HttpMethod method) {
        // Check if the path and method match any exclusion in the list
        return excludedRoutes.stream().anyMatch(routeConfig ->
                pathMatcher.match(routeConfig.getPath(), path) &&
                        (routeConfig.getMethod() == null || routeConfig.getMethod().equals(method))
        );
    }

    // Helper class to define route and method exclusions
    private static class RouteConfig {
        private final String path;
        private final HttpMethod method;

        public RouteConfig(String path, HttpMethod method) {
            this.path = path;
            this.method = method;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public HttpMethod getMethod() {
            return method;
        }
    }
}


logs:
ttp-nio-3] [                                                 ] c.O.api_gateway.auth.JwtAuthFilter       : JwtAuthFilter is processing the request
2024-10-29T01:21:22.102+05:30 DEBUG 32596 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] [                                                 ] c.O.api_gateway.auth.JwtAuthFilter       : Incoming request path: /api/item, method: POST
2024-10-29T01:21:22.658+05:30 DEBUG 32596 --- [api-gateway] [ctor-http-nio-3] [                                                 ] c.O.api_gateway.auth.JwtAuthFilter       : JWT token validated successfully
2024-10-29T01:21:22.675+05:30 DEBUG 32596 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-4] [                                                 ] c.O.api_gateway.auth.JwtAuthFilter       : Successfully completed processing for path: /api/item
2024-10-29T01:21:22.675+05:30 DEBUG 32596 --- [api-gateway] [     parallel-4] [                                                 ] c.O.api_gateway.auth.JwtAuthFilter       : Response status code: 401 UNAUTHORIZED

My down stream services where servlet based at first to avoid the incompatibility issues I have made my microservices reactive like those which have webflux dependency than web. I have tried with implementing authentication in one service but the result was same. Individually it works perfectly.

Is securityConfig set in the sub-service registered in the gateway's yml, etc.?

I have tried by setting securityConfig in one sub-service but there is no change

I think the gateway only performs jwt verification and does not need securityConfig.
https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway

I've got an explanation from documentation. The conclusion is, Simplify the gateway by using it purely as a request router, rather than an authentication manager, which may streamline request handling and reduce the risk of 401 errors due to authentication misalignments.

How was the result of your attempt?
